# Assert that the two lists have the same length. Create a list of all names and surnames

Tags: java, java-stream

0. Assert that the two lists have the same length. Done
1. Create a list of all names and surnames. Done
2. Is there any better way to do this ? or can the code be reduced? ---> I need help.

```
    static List<String> ex2(List<String> names, List<String> surnames) {
        if (names.size() != surnames.size()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("the two lists are not the same length");
    }
    List<String> n = names.stream().map(e -> 
    e.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    surnames.stream().map(e -> n.add(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return n;
    }
```

```
List<String> fname = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
List<String> lname = List.of("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L");
```

the output : [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L]

Comment: `names.addAll(surnames)`

Comment: Are you sure that your task is to append one list to the other? It would make more sense if your task is to append name and surname for each list position. That would explain why both lists must have the same size. And what’s the relevance of `map(e -> e.toUpperCase())`? This conversion does not appear in your task description and with your all-uppercase test data, you’re not even noticing its effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't need a specific order in the result list of names and surnames.
I would recommend to remove use of streams:

```java
static List<String> ex2(List<String> names, List<String> surnames) {
    if (names.size() != surnames.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("the two lists are not the same length");
    }
    List<String> namesAndSurnames = new ArrayList<>(names);
    namesAndSurnames.addAll(surnames);
    return namesAndSurnames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Stream.concat()` and `Stream.sorted()` functions. For example:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fname = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
        List<String> lname = List.of("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L");
        List<String> together = Stream.concat(fname.stream(), lname.stream()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(together);
    }
```